# Subversion or Mercurial SPI - What API shall a server implement?

Tags: java, git, svn, mercurial, webdav

I'm trying to evaluate a product idea that (besides the main, non-disclosed functionality) would provide a "revision control"-style secondary view of the content/changes. I expect many users, and I wouldn't create real repositories, I would like to store my internal data as I see fit - I would like to just emulate the Subversion or the Mercurial server.

I've quickly search for APIs, and although Subversion and Mercurial is rich on client API documentation, I couldn't find decent server-side API/SPI docs/specification.

I'm going to use Java, but any format in any language could be helpful to decide on the complexity and required effort. Git *might* be an option, but I have no experience with it.

Update #1: I am not seeking popularity of a given tool. I need the binary/REST/whatever protocol description of the given type of server that need to be implemented to "be" that kind of server.

Comment: What are you asking?  What is easiest to implement?  What is most likely to be popular?  My "shoot from the hip" answer is that you shouldn't do it.  Focus on what makes your product idea interesting, and leave the "bells and whistles" until you've got your product working and (paying) customers asking for them.

Comment: I am not seeking popularity of a given tool. I need the binary/REST/whatever protocol description of the given type of server that need to be implemented to "be" that kind of server.

Comment: Subversion can provide WebDAV access, which sounds like what you actually want to implement, no? Open standard for distributed version-control-type access?

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps this could help, it is the server side implementation of svn written in java.

- http://svn.svnkit.com/repos/svnkit/trunk/svnkit-dav/

If git is an option you should have a look at the jgit-http-server:

- https://github.com/eclipse/jgit/tree/master/org.eclipse.jgit.http.server

Answer (score 1):

You can find some information about Mercurial "API" in the following links :

1. https://www.mercurial-scm.org/wiki/WireProtocol
2. https://www.mercurial-scm.org/wiki/HttpCommandProtocol
3. https://www.mercurial-scm.org/wiki/SshCommandProtocol

The [CategoryInternals page](https://www.mercurial-scm.org/wiki/CategoryInternals) is also maybe worth reading.

If you want more information, I'm afraid you will have to read the code.

Comment: Thanks for the links! Unfortunately, if that is all the internal API documentation Mercurial publishes, then I need to dig into their python code - or forget/drop Mercurial support. Too bad either way...

Comment: @Steve Once you've digged into the python code, you can improve the documentation on the wiki ;) BTW, I don't think that emulate a Mercurial server, or any other VCS server in that matter, is really a good idea, it seems to me that it will be a real burden over the time... Good luck with your project !

Answer (score 1):

[Subversion's webdav and autoversioning support](http://oreilly.com/opensource/excerpts/9780596510336/webdav-and-autoversioning.html) might be the closest one what you are seeking, although I wouldn't bet on that it will be easy :)